# Brackets aren't working on this Windows File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

I am new here and my english is not very good so first, pardon me.

My problem is that this batch keep reading the strings inside the variable "IF EXIST %FSIZE%"; i meant, in case that variable does not exist, the batch keep reading inside the () brackets instead go on the rest of the stings.

If %FSIZE% exist, the batch perform the 2 task i assign: (1.) If size is equal, goto cifiles5x. (2.) If size is NOT equal it uses 7z to extract the file i want to be there.

If %FSIZE% DOES NOT EXIST, the batch keep saying "765952 was not expect at this moment".

I am taking the advices on ss64.com like don't use brackets or quotes when comparing numeric values (%size% EQU 765952) but i don't understand why it does not continue to where the ) ends.

I have also try to link the commands with "&&" so i can erase the brackets but the results are the same.

**I know there's 2 spaced patches without quotes; they are unquoted because if i did the size checker won't work.**

Thanks for reading this.
**EDIT:** Batch modified according to suggestions made.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Log checker
COLOR 0F
SET FSIZE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Ces\Log Files Ver\LogVbReg_r2.dll
SET InsDIR=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Ces\Log Files Ver\
REM I didn't add "" on FSIZE and InsDIR because if i did, quote the variable will
REM result a doubled quoted patch and won't work.
CLS
ECHO ==============================================================================
ECHO =                                Log checker                                 =
ECHO ==============================================================================
ECHO Checking if exist:
ECHO "%FSIZE%"
IF EXIST "%FSIZE%" (
ECHO It does exist, checking size...
FOR %%A IN ("%FSIZE%") DO SET SIZE=%%~ZA
IF "%SIZE%" EQU "765952"
ECHO Size is right, jumping to CIFILES5
GOTO CIFILES5x 
) ELSE (
ECHO Size is not right, extracting the needed file...
7z.exe e "Data_X.*" -o"%InsDIR%" -y "LogVbReg_r2.dll"
GOTO CIFILES5x)
ECHO Does not exist; extracting file...
REN Data_X.* Data_X.exe
Data_X.exe
TIMEOUT 2>NUL
REN DATA_X.* Data_X.dat
:CIFILES5x
ECHO Reach cifiles5x
PAUSE
IF EXIST "%TEMP%\9513.CES" (GOTO OPS) ELSE (GOTO LNKD)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have space in your file name of %FSIZE%. As result text after space it is treated as command for `if`. Try using quotes around `"%FSIZE%"` or do `CD` to folder first and than check for just file name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I change it by this: (Still the same problem)
    SET InsDIR=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Ces\Log Files Ver\
    CD "%InsDIR%"
    SET FSIZE=LogVbReg_r2.dll